# Can't use @RequestBody with PostMapping only with GetMapping

Tags: java, spring

If I use `@GetMapping` and `@RequestBody` everything works fine, but if I change only `@GetMapping` to `@PostMapping` I get this error in postman:

> ```
> "status": 403,
> "error": "Forbidden",
> "message": "Forbidden",
> ```

```
    @GetMapping(value =  "/insert") //works
       public Long insert(@RequestBody T entity){
          ...
       }
    }

    @PostMapping(value =  "/insert") //does not work
       public Long insert(@RequestBody T entity){
          ...
       }
    }
```

Comment: `403` is a security reject response, not a mapping error response, so you probably didn't configure Spring Security to allow POST.

Comment: http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

Comment: Is that the only one? Did you also enable method-level security? Perhaps `insert()` is calling a service method the user is not authorized to call? I'm guessing here, given the severe lack of information available to us.

Comment: ok its definitely spring-boot-starter-security, I removed it and now it works fine, i will search what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@GetMapping and @PostMapping are Spring MVC annotations, but [403](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) - is a security issue related HTTP code. So the problem is definitely in Spring Security configurations.

There is high chances that the purpose of the issue is CSRF protection that is enabled by default in Spring Security.

To give it a try, please to disable [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection in your config in a following way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Afterwards, POST requests should be allowed within the application.

Comment: thanks it works but isn't a security thread if csrf is disabled globally?

Comment: Well, it depends: if the server isn't used globally but by another services within the application - it's ok to have it disabled. Otherwise, it worth configuring sending CSRF token for each request type that modify the state of the server (speaking about the CRUD: POST, PUT, PATCH and DELETE types).